# How to remove a project short cut from VSCode

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

So I am new to both Mac and VSCode but one of the unwarranted feature of either VSCode or Mac is just freaking me out. Hopefully someone can help me with this.

Basically, when I right click VSCode in the bottom dock of mac then it shows   list of `Recently used projects` list to choose from without showing me full paths to them. So if I opened a project from two locations then it will show me both of them in the list and both of them show up as identical options because `shortcut feature` only cares about the names NOT the full paths. Which just makes things confusing. I just want to remove one of the two entries from this list that I see when I right click   on VS Code icon in `The Dock`. How can I do that?

Below is the screen where `Recent items show up and I want to remove an item from`

[image]

Comment: No. It is not the same question. The one that you referred to is addressing the issue of `removing a FILE from recent history`. What I am asking is that if there is a way to remove current directory from "recently opened projects history" of Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Open the command pallete by selecting it from the View dropdown or by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>.
2. Enter the `File: Clear Recently Opened` command.
3. Restart Visual Studio Code.

At this point your recently opened directories will be empty.  Unfortunately there is no way to target a single directory for removal.

Comment: The workaround described in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74531770/8381175) works for the use case where you just have to remove a shortcut for a single project.

Answer (score 1):

I have just found a workaround which seems to remove a single directory.

1. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (you may need <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> instead if using a Mac) and select `File: Open Recent...`
2. After you click on that, you should see a dropdown with your recently opened projects. Hover with the mouse on the one you want to delete and towards the end of the line you're hovering you should see a small `x` appearing
3. Click on that `x` and you're all done